# Как собрать исполняемый jar в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jar

Разрабатываю приложение в студии. И клиентская и серверная часть пока были единым целым, но понадобилось запускать сервер удаленно, затем подключаться к нему клиентом. Собрать APK файл - элементарно, но как собрать jar для запуска сервера - так и не разобрался. Может кто-то сталкивался?

Как посоветовал @ЮрийСПб, открыл панель Gradle, но не нашел в ней нужных assembleDebug/resease для сборки. Использую LibGDX, запуск сервера происходит в методе main отдельного класса.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Справа вверху студии есть панель gradle в ней найдите assembleDebug/resease получите файл

Comment: Юрий, дополнил вопрос картинкой и уточнениями. Где конкретно там это найти можно? Не нашел ни одного, который бы соответствовал названию моего класса-запускатора сервера..

Comment: Вроде где-то в build должно быть... И сам модуль должен как либа быть отмечен в gradle.